# How to structure postgreSQL db for multiple different variations of a form

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am working on an app where users fill in various reports and submit them. They're currently stored in a table called "Reports". Each field in the report is stored in its own column. Some columns are used in a subset of report types, while most are only used in a single report type.

For example: Report 1 uses columns A, B and C. Report 2 uses columns A, B, D and E. Report 3 uses columns A, B, C and F. And so on...

This has worked fine, but we're adding new report types frequently and I'm concerned about scaling. Each report has a core set of input fields that are the same for all types. As we add new reports, we're accumulating new columns that are only used for one specific report type. We're past 100 columns now and growing and this will likely continue for a long time. It's realistic that we could one day exceed the 1600 column limit for the table.

My question is, what is the best way to store these reports so that we're not just adding on new columns for every new report type?

I have two ideas in mind, but I would appreciate any input or alternative suggestions!

**Idea 1**: Create a table for every report type. Store the report type and PK, then join on the PK from the corresponding table when the report record is pulled.

Rationale: This is a more normalized structure and it keeps the Reports table in a manageable state.

Drawbacks: We would have multiple tables with the same columns and we would need a new table for every single report. So, instead of 100+ columns, we have 100+ tables...Doesn't seem right

**Idea 2**: Replace the non-core columns with a JSON Type column. Store the auxiliary fields as key:value pairs.

Rationale: I've seen NoSQL proposed as a solution for the situation I described in my question. Replacing our DB with a NoSQL solution is impractical at the moment and adding a secondary NoSQL db for this purpose would be its own large effort. This feels like a good compromise with the same benefits.

Drawbacks: Aside from needing to combine the JSON object with the rest of the record, maybe a performance hit? Not sure what else.

Comment: How about the option to make one table for report with a one-to-many relationship with the columns reply_id, report_type, messahe.?

Comment: Idea #1.5: multiple tables, but normalize out different sets of columns into different tables, so that there are no duplicate columns apart from the primary key

Comment: @Charlieface there will be some duplicates, but you’re absolutely right that the core fields should be in the base table.  That’s 1NF.

Comment: Both solutions sound OK.

Comment: Is there any concern with having potentially hundreds of tables (eventually) using idea 1?

Comment: Why would there be? Although if you are routinely just querying all possible columns from all tables then yes JSON or XML might be better, as hundreds of left joins is going to bug up the compiler. But it makes sense to normalize to separate tables when you plan on querying that data individually. So what type of queries are you planning on doing?

Comment: Most common use case is pulling a group of records from the reports table and filtering on any field. In a rare case, we may pull all records from the table. Nothing particularly unusual.

Comment: When you say *any* field: are you going to want to filter report 1 on column  E even though it doesn't have it?

Comment: No, we would be more attentive than that :) Filter on report type(s) before filtering on a column

Comment: For those interested, it looks like we'll go with the JSON column solution. I will update here when we've finished (will likely be a while)